# AppCenter error (sudo apt-get update)

Tags: appcenter

I get the following when trying to use AppCenter... [image: AppCenter Error]

As an alternative, I get the following from using "sudo apt-get update"
http://dpaste.com/2NZ5H5T

Comment: I can't update from app center or the $ prompt, I get this error: E: Type '<!DOCTYPE' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was resolved, everything's back to normal :)

[image]

Comment: elementary OS moved to Github, so I would suggest opening an issue here: https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues/

Comment: reported by an elementary user here: https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues/630

Comment: it seems that it has been resolved.

Comment: Me still having exact same issue & commented on the issue 630 above